# ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu

Tags: python, cuda, theano

**When I run import theano the error is as follows:**

```
['nvcc', '-shared', '-g', '-O3', '--compiler-bindir', 'C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\bin# flags=-m32 # we have this hard coded fornow', '-Xlinker', '/DEBUG', '-m32', '-Xcompiler', 'DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=d67f7c8a21306c67152a70a88a837011,/Zi,/MD', '-IC:\\TheanoPython\\python-2.7.6\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\sandbox\\cuda', '-IC:\\TheanoPython\\python-2.7.6\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include', '-IC:\\TheanoPython\\python-2.7.6\\include', '-o',
 'C:\\Users\\Matej\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-2.7.6-32\\cuda_ndarray\\cuda_ndarray.pyd', 'mod.cu', '-LC:\\TheanoPython\\python-2.7.6\\libs', '-LNone\\lib', '-LNone\\lib64', '-LC:\\TheanoPython\\python-2.7.6', '-lpython27', '-lcublas', '-lcudart']
ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu: ('nvcc return status', 1, 'for cmd', 'nvcc -shared -g -O3 --compiler-bindir C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\bin# flags=-m32 # we have this hard codedfor now -Xlinker /DEBUG -m32 -Xcompiler DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=d67f7c8a21306c67152a70a88a837011,/Zi,/MD -IC:\\TheanoPython\\python-2.7.6\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\sandbox\\cuda -IC:\\TheanoPython\\python-2.7.6\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include -IC:\\TheanoPython\\python-2.7.6\\include -o C:\\Users\\Matej\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-2.7.6-32\\cuda_ndarray\\cuda_ndarray.pyd mod.cu -LC:\\TheanoPython\\python-2.7.6\\libs -LNone\\lib -LNone\\lib64 LC:\\TheanoPython\\python-2.7.6 -lpython27 -lcublas -lcudart')
WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu is not available
```

**The contents of my .theanorc file are as follows:**

```
[blas]  
ldflags =   
[gcc]  
cxxflags = -IC:\Anaconda\MinGW\bin 
[cuda]
root = C:\cuda\cudatoolkit\bin
[nvcc]  
fastmath = True  
flags=-LC:\Anaconda\libs  
compiler-bindir=C:\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin
[global]  
floatX = float32  
device = gpu0
openmp = False
```

**And the Environment variable is as follows：**

```
C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\MinGW\bin;C:\Anaconda\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib;
C:\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin;C:\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib;
C:\Program Files(x86)\NVIDIACorporation\PhysX\Common;C:\cuda\cudatoolkit\bin;
```

If I run import theano without the GPU option on, it runs without a problem. Also CUDA samples run without a problem.I have confirmed that the computer GPU has been opened.
A few weeks ago，i had run it without a problem. Because of a software everything was unwork. Now the problem confuse me...

Comment: This error message is the generic Theano response when your CUDA installation is broken. Any one of a large number of things might be wrong. The solution is to fix your CUDA installation. But that is the only answer anyone here can provide.

Comment: thanks,but my cuda installation is OK. i have verified it.

Comment: It can also mean that your CUDA version doesn't match the version that Theano was built against, or that your GPU doesn't support cuDNN, or any one of a number of other problems.

Comment: FYI: [How to install Theano on Kubuntu 14.04 x64, and configure it so that it uses the GPU?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33743346/395857)

Comment: I have done the following steps in the text, when the gpu_test.py file is executed , the same mistake occoured..