# Importing theano: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'find_graphviz'

Tags: python, theano

When I run `import theano` in Python, I get the following error message:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import theano
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from theano.printing import pprint, pp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/printing.py", line 35, in <module>
    if pd.find_graphviz():
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'find_graphviz'
```

What could be the issue, and how to fix it?

I use Theano 0.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS x64 with Python 2.7.6 x64.

---

I unsuccessfully tried:

- `sudo apt-get install -y graphviz libgraphviz-dev`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In `pydot` 1.2.x version,`find_graphviz` function have been [deprecated](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/issues/126). To fix this issue, you should install pydot 1.1.0 version here https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/tree/v1.1.0 . And it is work for me. May help.

Comment: Thanks, I see that some people [recommend](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/commit/8d4e0fd0053496ccfed002ea2898a09627443e4e) `pydot-ng`

Comment: If you need an older version of a python package like pydot, just specify it during install or in your `requirements.txt`, like this: `pip install pydot==1.1.0`

Comment: @hobs I am unable to install pydot 1.1.0 version. Any idea to resolve this issue - Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-yfv0rpvl/pydot/

Comment: @joel this sounds like a new question. I'm sure someone on the wider community can help you with that better than I could,  if you asked it as a top level question.

Answer (score 11):

I solved by installing pydot-ng --> **`$ pip install pydot-ng`**

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, the Python module `pydot` was creating the issue:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import pydot
>>> pydot.find_graphviz()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'find_graphviz'
```

I was using pydot 1.2.2.

I uninstalled it using `sudo pip uninstall -y pydot`, and I then was able to successfully `import theano`.

Bug report: https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/4759

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by using

```
sudo pip install graphviz
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

with the pydot version 1.2.3 works fine