# `from theano import * ` failed - no attribute `find-graphviz`

Tags: python, theano

I am attempting to import theano. As I tried

```
from theano import *
```

it showed

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'find_graphviz'.
```

I read this post [Importing theano: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'find_graphviz'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446771/importing-theano-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-find-graphvi) and `$git clone https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot.git`, `$pip install pydot`.

However, this does not work for me. As I returned to ipython and `from theano import *` I still got the same error. I also unsuccessfully tried `sudo apt-get install -y graphviz libgraphviz-dev`. Would anyone have a different solution? Thank you!!

Comment: Have you tried `pip install pydot-ng`?

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem. :)